# Oracle BI Publisher multiple select parameters

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, obiee, bi-publisher

I have a requirement to have multiple select parameters on a BI Publisher report.  I am passing the parameters to a function that turns a comma separated list of values to a table.  I then use the tables from the csv parser function in "IN" statements in the where clause. It looks likes below...

```
select * from table(my_report_function(my_csv_parser_function(:Parameter))
```

This works fine when I run it in SQL Developer.  The problem is that seems when BI Publisher passes the parameter it interprets each comma as a separate parameter so I get an invalid number of parameters error.  How can I stop it from doing this or is there a better way to handle multiple select parameters being passed to a function?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, parameter is passed just as line in sql query in order to use this parameter in sql query later.

In your case it can be for example :

```
select * from table(my_report_function(my_csv_parser_function(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

Instead you can use this parameter in yours sql query.
In my case for example it is:

```
select *
from dev_dmart.FCT_CURRENCY_RATE
WHERE FROM_CURRENCY_CD = 840
and TO_CURRENCY_CD IN (:multiple_select_parameter_list)
```

In your case it can be something like this:

```
select * from table(my_report_function())
where field in (:Parameter)
```

Or you can create Event Trigger on "Before data" in Publisher and call function there which will calculate data and insert it in TABLE (for example PRECALCULATED_DATA).
And in report you can then use query:

select * from PRECALCULATED_DATA
    where field in (:Parameter)

Comment: I do the second example all the time.  What I need is how to pass a multiple select parameter to a function.  There is one particular multiple select parameter that I have that requires me to use a different query, so I want to write a single PL/SQL function that will run one of two queries based on whether the user selects a value in this particular parameter.  I wrote a function that does this just fine in SQL Developer, but BIP gives me an invalid number of parameters error when I try to use it.